# Iterate through excel cell ranges and mimic color fill for both

Tags: excel, vba, background-color, fill

In excel using VBA, I am rying to write a formula that takes in 2 columns (or ranges of cells) as arguments. Iterate through each cell of the arguments and assign the cell's fill/color of the first argument to the adjacent (same row) cell in the second argument. This is what I have

```
Public Function ColoredCol(sourceCol As Range, destCol As Range)
    For n = destCol.Row To destCol.Rows.Count
        destCol(n, destCol.Column).Interior.ColorIndex =sourceCol(n, sourceCol.Column).Interior.ColorIndex
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: This should be a `Sub`, not a `Function`.

Comment: Functions cannot change properties of cells, so as @BigBen said, make it a `Sub` procedure. (Therefore, this type of action cannot be called upon via the worksheet (i.e. - `=ColoredCol(A1:A10,B1:B10)`)

Comment: Unless destCol starts at row 1 you won't get all of the cells you are expecting. I would suggest looping the range using each cell in the range and then using the formatting property you are interested in. There is nothing to ensure that the start row or the size of the 2 ranges are the same.